# Can we send push notifications to apps that use our SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Lets suppose some app developers use our SDK. Can we send push notifications to devices that use our SDK independently, without the help of hosted app?

I know that push is unique to every app , multiple push keys , settings can't be made.

But I just like to know if any other options are available.

Our goal is to send push for devices that use our SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using Apple Push Notifications. Sending an Apple Push Notification to an iOS Application requires a certificate that is unique for each application. You would need to receive the certificates from the developers of those apps.

In addition, the apps would have to register to APNS and send the device token to your server. This part can be done as part of your SDK, assuming the users of your SDK call some SDK method that performs the registration and sends the token.